# Lebesgue integral exist

Tags: lebesgue-integral

They ask me to determine the $ p $ values ​​for which the following Lebesgue integrals exist
$$ \int_0 ^ {\infty} x ^ x e ^ {- x^{p} } dx$$
I have to see when it is finite, but the analysis is quite complicated mainly because in all my degree I do not deal with the integral of $x ^ x$ so I investigated but it is not clear to me until the moment of doing some calculations I have to $ p $ in $ [1, \infty) $ but in the other cases I don't know how to proceed, if you have any advice or help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The original question is $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{x}e^{-xp}dx$:**

For any $p$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{x}e^{-xp}dx=\infty$, there is no such $p$ for which the integral exists as a real number.

For the new question, for $p>1$, first we observe that 
\begin{align*}
\log\dfrac{x^{x}}{e^{x^{p}}}=x\log x-x^{p}\leq C_{q}x^{q}-x^{p},
\end{align*}
for some $1<q<p$ and constant $C_{q}>0$, so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x^{x}}{e^{x^{p}}}\leq e^{C_{q}x^{q}-x^{p}}.
\end{align*}
But now we compare with $e^{-x^{p}/2}$:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{e^{C_{q}x^{q}-x^{p}}}{e^{-x^{p}/2}}\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
To see this comparison, note that
\begin{align*}
\log\dfrac{e^{C_{q}x^{q}-x^{p}}}{e^{-x^{p}/2}}=C_{q}x^{q}-x^{p}+\dfrac{x^{p}}{2}=x^{q}\left(C_{q}-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{p-q}\right)\rightarrow-\infty
\end{align*}
as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

But it is now easy to see that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{p}/2}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
so the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{x}e^{-x^{p}}dx<\infty.
\end{align*}
Keep in mind that we start with $p>1$.

But for $p\leq 1$, we have $x^{x}e^{-x^{p}}\rightarrow\infty$. To see this, once again we take the $\log$ to have
\begin{align*}
x\log x-x^{p}=x^{p}\left(x^{1-p}\log x-1\right)\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align*} 
So the integral in this case cannot exist as a real number.

Comment: Sorry but when I edited it for the second time I forgot to put that it is $- x$ to $p$ $$ \int_0 ^ {\infty} x ^ x e ^ {- x^{p} } dx$$

Comment: Now you may take a look of it.

Comment: Thanks, for you help.